# Как добавить елемент в список при работе с RxJava?

Tags: android, rxjava

Суть: Есть список юзеров, нужно его промапить и собрать из него `List<ICardItem>`

Как я это делаю

```
@NonNull
@Override
public List<ICardItem> decompose(@NonNull final List<User> iObj)
{
    return Observable.fromIterable(iObj)//
                     .observeOn(mWorkScheduler)//
                     .map(this::extractFrom)//
                     .flatMapIterable(i -> i)//
                     .toList()//
                     .observeOn(mResultScheduler)//
                     .blockingGet();
}
```

Ну и вот мок метод

```
@NotNull
private List<ICardItem> extractFrom(@NotNull User iObj)
{
    return new ArrayList<ICardItem>()
    {{
        add(new ButtonCardItem());
    }};
}
```

Что происходит? Я беру по очереди каждого юзера, мапаю его и получаю список нужных мне елементов, потом эти списки `List<List<ICardItem>>` соединяю в один список `List<ICardItem>` и вот на выходе то, что мне нужно

Но теперь есть поправка, нужно к этому списку добавить еще 2 елемента `ICardItem` один вверх `index 0` и один вниз `index list.size`

Вот и вопрос

Как это сделать, чтоб это не выглядело костыльно?

Есть ли какой нибудь метод типо `addFirst` и `addLast`?

Comment: После `toList` добавить `map` и в нём добавить элементы в список.

Comment: Возможно помогут операторы `startWith()` и `concatWith()`

Comment: @VasilBaymurzin спасибо! Это то , что мне было нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге получается вот так

Как сказал @VasilBaymurzin нужно использовать `startWith()` и `concatWith()` операторы, где `startWith()` добавляет элементы в начало списка и `concatWith()` в конец.

> Кстати для инфо насчет оператора `concatWith()` его функция не добавление элементов в список, он просто принимает в параметр какой нибудь `ObservableSourse` и за счет того, что выполняется этот оператор синхронно это значит, что все что будет в его обзервабле будет выполняться согласно порядку.

Так вот в итоге как выглядит у меня

```
@NonNull
@Override
public List<ICardItem> decompose(@NonNull final List<User> iObj)
{
    return Observable.fromIterable(iObj)//
                     .observeOn(mWorkScheduler)//
                     .map(this::extractFrom)//
                     .flatMapIterable(i -> i)//
                     .startWith(Observable.fromArray(new RefreshHeaderCardItem(), new ButtonCardItem()))
                     .concatWith(Observable.fromArray(new AdvertisementCardItem(), new IntermediateCardItem(IntermediateCardItem.TRANSPARENT)))
                     .toList()
                     .observeOn(mResultScheduler)//
                     .blockingGet();
}
```